# Filter nested JSON objects with an array of objects

Tags: arrays, reactjs, search, data-structures, mapreduce

I have a search bar where you type employee name and it should return the name based on a filter. I have a nested JSON object (as shown below) where I need to drill into the object to access the employee's names in the array.

My problem is the code is not filtering the names and returning all the names not the names searched for. I get this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`

Question: I need to map the element twice, how would I do this?

*UPDATE: No answers helped me. The 2nd answer has to do with querying and is very complicated for the simple answer I am looking for, and the 1st answer has a different data structure than mine.*

*SECOND UPDATE:* Click [here for the soultion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68689006/filter-a-nested-json-object/68689259#68689259)
I also added this to the thread below

added the below for more clarity
WHAT i have tried:

```
  const results = company.filter((comp) =>
  comp.details.employee.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase())
);

  const results = company.map((el) => {
    return {...el, dets: el.dets.filter((details) => 
    details.employee.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase()))}
  })

  const results = company.filter((comp) => r.details.map((innerArr) => {
      return innerArr.employee.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase());
    })
  );

  const results = company.filter((comp) => {
    return res.details.map((inner) =>
      inner.employee.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase())
    );
  });
```

added the below for more clarity
*The following code works to access the employee names in another component: how can I implement the above in the below code*

```
{test.map((result) => (result.details.map((innerArr) => 
  <h5>{innerArr.employee}</h5>
  )))}

      const SearchByEmpComp = () => {
      const [company, setCompany] = useState([
    {
      "company": "HIJ",
      "_id": "1",
      "details": 
      [
          {
              "employee": "Lesley Peden",
              "notes": "Lesley's note",
              "_id": "2"
          }
      ],
    },
    {
     "company": "ABC",
     "_id": "3",
     "details": 
      [
         {
             "employee": "David Barton",
             "notes": "some note!!",
             "_id": "4"
         }
      ],
   }
]);
    
  //below code I need to edit with nested map
      const test = company.filter((r) => 
      r.details.map((innerArr) => {
      return innerArr.employee.toLowerCase().includes
      (searchField.toLowerCase());
  })
  );

  const deatils = () => {
    if (searchShow) 
      return <EmpDetailsByName test={test} />
    }
  };

return (
    <>
    <FormControl
      type="search"
    />
      <div>
        <Button
          onClick={handleClick}
        >
          Enter
        </Button>
        <div>{deatils()}</div>
      </div
  );
};
```

Comment: It looks like your `company` array of objects which you're passing to your initial state (`useState()` function) is malformed. Should `details` be an object there?

Comment: The `company` array syntax definitely is broken, especially `details`. Is the latter supposed to carry many `employee` items? Anything else does not really make sense. Also, can a `Jane Smith` or a `John Doe` each exist once for a company but in many companies at the same time. This too would be a real world use case.

Comment: I am getting the data from MongoDB and Axios requests, I forgot to add the `{}` details in an array of objects. Yes, I tried to directly use employee but it did not work. I have updated the code with the added `{}`

Comment: @Julie The example data is still malformed/broken. The code can not even be verified easily by eyesight due to not being formatted well. Please validate and format any code block before publishing it. **Hints** ... `employee: Lesley Pede` - missing quotes ... `details [ ... ]` - missing colon assignment ...

Comment: @PeterSeliger I updated the code - copied from postman

Comment: @Julie ... 1/2 ... I updates the source data of my executable example code as well. But of cause this did not effect the approach I came up with in/from the very beginning since the predicted data structure did prove itself. Is there anything you can take from the writings? Do you understand the transformation steps and why they are needed?

Comment: @Julie ... 2/2 ... I suggest, that for search queries based on possible employee names one does run the filter with an already by `createListOfCompanyEmployees` computed array. Thus the query always can be executed immediately. The array has to be updated only in case the main business data does change.

Comment: @PeterSeliger thank you for your solution, however, there is too much code to implement, I need to map the elements twice, once by the company and second by details.employee, but I cannot figure out how to do this in the current way the code  function is written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all credit due to **Zachary Haber**:
This is the CORRECT solution to my question

```
  const test = company.map((element) => {
  return {
  ...element,
  details: element.details.filter((details) =>
    details.employee.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase())
  ),
};
```

});

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```js
const searchField = 'Les';
const company = [
  {
    company: 'ABC',
    details: [
      {
        employee: 'Lesley Peden',
        _id: 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    company: 'EFG',
    details: [
      {
        employee: 'Wayne Smith',
        _id: 2
      }
    ]
  },
];

const results = company.find(comp =>
  comp.details.filter(inner =>
    inner.employee.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase())
));

console.log(results);
```

And print it out in a similar fashion in HTML.

Comment: I updated my data structure it is an array with objects so this solution does not work, i just tried to implement

Comment: Thank you errata, I applied and still getting the error as before, in the solution that worked for me, the spread operator was used and it really helped me drill down to the employee names. See below solution,

I appreciate your time and effort and feel your code could possibly help others so I upvoted it :)

Answer (score -1):

The OP's `company` array syntax definitely is broken, especially the `details` array.

I suppose the latter is going to contain many employee items; anything else does not really make sense.

Also, a `Jane Smith` or a `John Doe` have to exist each exactly once per company but of cause can occur each in more than just one company at the same time. This too is a real world use case.

Thus an assumed correct data source format would look more like ...

```
[{
  company: "ABC",
  details: [{
    employee: "Lesley Peden",
    _id: 1,
  }, {
    employee: "John Doe",
    _id: 2,
  }, {
    employee: "Jane Smith",
    _id: 3,
  }],
}, {
  company: "EFG",
  details: [{
    employee: "John Doe",
    _id: 1,
  }, {
    employee: "Jane Smith",
    _id: 2,
  }, {
    employee: "Wayne Smith",
    _id: 3,
  }],
}];
```

Thus an approach has to collect and normalize any ***employee item*** from each ***company item's*** `details` array. In order to not loose the relation to its ***company item*** any ***employee item*** does get assigned its related company.

This happens during an initial mapping and standardized item creation process. An ***employee item*** like `{ employee: "Lesley Peden", _id: 1 }` which belongs to the ***company item*** `company: "ABC"` gets mapped temporarily into a standardized ***company employee item***   ... `{ "companyName": "ABC", "employeeId": 1, "employee": "Lesley Peden" }`.

In a second aggregation/reducer step this temporary list of standardized ***company employee items*** gets transformed into a list of ***employee `name`*** based items, where each item does feature an additional `companies` array which reflects the ***one name*** to ***many companies*** relationship by containing not just one, but maybe more ***company items*** which for a name like `John Doe` will most probably look like this ...

```
{
  name: "John Doe",
  companies: [{
    companyName: "ABC",
    employeeId: 2,
  }, {
    companyName: "EFG",
    employeeId: 1,
  }],
}
```

An array of such items of cause can be easily filtered by each item's `name` property via (fragmented) name search queries which the beneath approach will demonstrate by some executable example code ...

```js
function createEmployeeWithBoundCompanyData({ _id:employeeId, ...employeeValue }) {
  return { ...this, employeeId, ...employeeValue };
}

function aggregateEmployeeItems(collector, companyEmployee) {
  const { employee:name, ...employeeValue } = companyEmployee;
  const { index, list } = collector;

  const employeeItem = index[name] ??= { name, companies: [] };

  if (employeeItem.companies.length === 0) {
    list.push(employeeItem);
  }
  employeeItem.companies.push(employeeValue);

  return collector;
}
function collectCompanyEmployees(employeeList, companyItem) {
  const { company:companyName, _id:companyId, details } = companyItem;
  return employeeList.concat(
    details.map(
      createEmployeeWithBoundCompanyData,
      { companyName, companyId },
    )
  );
}

function createListOfCompanyEmployees(companyListsOfEployees) {
  return companyListsOfEployees
    .reduce(collectCompanyEmployees, [])
    .reduce(aggregateEmployeeItems, { index: {}, list: [] }).list;
}

function queryCompanyEmployeesByName(companyListsOfEployees, query) {
  return createListOfCompanyEmployees(companyListsOfEployees)
    .filter(({ name }) =>
      name.trim().toLowerCase().includes(
        query.trim().toLowerCase()
      )
    );
}

console.log(
  'createListOfCompanyEmployees(companyList) ...',
  createListOfCompanyEmployees(companyList)
);
console.log(
  "queryCompanyEmployeesByName(companyList, 'Smith') ...",
  queryCompanyEmployeesByName(companyList, 'Smith')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
  const companyList = [{
    company: "ABC",
    _id: "aaaa-bbbb-cccc-0000",
    details: [{
      employee: "Lesley Peden",
      notes: "some notes about Lesley Peden",
      _id: "aaaa-bbbb-cccc-0001",
    }, {
      employee: "John Doe",
      notes: "some notes about John Doe",
      _id: "aaaa-bbbb-cccc-0002",
    }, {
      employee: "Jane Smith",
      notes: "some notes about Jane Smith",
      _id: "aaaa-bbbb-cccc-0003",
    }],
  }, {
    company: "EFG",
    _id: "dddd-eeee-ffff-0000",
    details: [{
      employee: "John Doe",
      notes: "some notes about John Doe",
      _id: "dddd-eeee-ffff-0001",
    }, {
      employee: "Jane Smith",
      notes: "some notes about Jane Smith",
      _id: "dddd-eeee-ffff-0002",
    }, {
      employee: "Wayne Smith",
      notes: "some notes about Wayne Smith",
      _id: "dddd-eeee-ffff-0003",
    }],
  }];
</script>
```